# Techniques to prove the monotonicity of an integral as a function of parameter

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Dear Stackexchange community,

I am studying the following integral as a function of parameter $a$:
$$I(a)=\int_1^\infty e^{-\frac{1+x}{2a}}\frac{1}{a\sqrt{x}{(1-erf(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a}})})^2}(erf(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})-erf(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}))dx$$
where $erf$ is the error function $erf(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt$.

I am trying to prove that $I(a)$ is decreasing in $a$. All sorts of numerical analysis confirms that this is so. Also, the nature of the problem where this comes from suggests that it should be the case (it is a density of a truncated distribution multiplied by another density).

The function under the integral looks as follows:
[image]

I wonder what techniques exist to prove such a fact. Taking a derivative doesn't seem to help: it is a messy integral of a function that is sometimes positive and sometimes negative.

Thank you for any advice.